# gwt or java based frameworks that allow easy web app ui design for pcs as well as tablets/smartphones

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt, smartgwt

I know that Smart GWT also supports Android and iOS, as well as regular PC/iPAD for UI design.

Is there any other good Java based or GWT based framework, that allows creation of interfaces for web apps, that show correctly in iOS/Android/Blackberry, as well as desktops/tablets?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Vaadin before and they have a TouchKit project that aims at mobile development. Vaadin is a server-side framework, so offline applications can be a problem. Anyway, some links:

- [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home)
- [TouchKit Addon](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/102)
- [Using TouckKit](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin%20TouchKit%20-%20Create%20iPhone%20applications%20using%20Vaadin)